# c++ passing class member function pointer to another function

Tags: c++, class, templates, vector, pointer-to-member

I searched in internet and I found some solution but I don't want to change my whole code.
I want to search in `vector<my_class *>` for a different object, so I wrote this but it doesn't work:

```
static vector <attendant *> attendant_vec;
template<typename T, typename R>
int binary_search(int first_cell, int last_cell,int search_key, vector<T*>& v, R (T::*func)(void), void *sort){
    int index;
    quicksort(v, v.size(), 0, sort);
    if(first_cell > last_cell)
        return -1;
    else {
        int middle = (first_cell + last_cell)/2;
        if(search_key== v.at(middle).*func())
            index=middle;
        else
            if(search_key< v.at(middle).*func())
                index=binary_search(first_cell, middle-1, search_key, v, func,sort);
            else
                index=binary_search(middle+1, last_cell, search_key, v, func,sort);
    }
    return index;
}

void my_function() {
    int u = binary_search(0,attendant_vec.size(),12,
            attendant_vec,&attendant::get_personal_code,
            &sort_by_personal_code);//ERROR
    cout<<u;
}
```

I've got these errors :

> Multiple markers at this line
>
> - no matching function for call to ‘binary_search(int, std::vector::size_type, int, std::vector&, int
>     (attendant::*)()const, bool    (*)(attendant*, attendant*))’
> - candidates are:
> - deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘_FIter’ (‘int’ and ‘long unsigned int’)
> - types ‘R (T::)()’ and ‘int (attendant::)()const’ have incompatible cv-qualifiers

Comment: could you give a minimal-case scenario and de-obfuscate the variables?

Comment: D47'$ $0/\/\3 L337 (0D3 d00D

Comment: double underscore leads to UB.

Comment: ok - i will edit code . it is about binary search algo function , i want search my vector<my_class> for couple of objects , but i don't want write 2 different search function to do it i want use function pointer and pass each ( give_object_name ) function to search function and use it .

Comment: I've edited your code to be human readable. Rollback if it's not 1337 enough for you.

Comment: @AlexM. That hurt my brain...

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [`std::binary_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search) as follows:

```
void my_function() {
    int u = std::binary_search(attendant_vec.begin(), attendant_vec.end(), 12, &sort_by_personal_code);
    std::cout << u;
}
```

Comment: i want to write it myself!